# SSL Certificate in my bitnami WordPress multi site, still in grey lock with yellow warning sign

Tags: wordpress, https, ssl-certificate, bitnami

NEED HELP: I installed ssl certificate in my wordpress website (bitnami) via ssh bncert-tool the installation said it was successful and https is redirected but my website still shows grey lock with yellow warning site saying connection not secure.

Please help me fix it.

I completed the process described here:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/understand-bncert/

and tried reinstalling many times, still getting se issues.

Please let me know how can I fix it and make the connection secured.

Comment: need some information, connection not secure can be caused if you have the main index page on https but reference of css/js etc are still referred on http.

Answer (score 0):

The grey lock icon means that some of the content is getting loaded from unsecured sources.  This can happen if your theme or plugin is loading images/CSS/javascript from unsecured (HTTP) URL.

You can view the source and check if you see HTTP in URLs or use Chrom's debugger console to see if any assets are loaded from unsecured sources.

you need further assistance, post your sites URL to debug further.